# TIKI Custom menu no any CSS applied

Tags: tiki-wiki

I setup TIKI13.0 on ubuntu12.04, it works for me, however what make me crazy is that my custom menu seem no any CSS applied.

My menu has been assigned to a custom module 'Document',

> {menu id=43 type=horiz}

and my module is positioned at pagetop, just as below image
[image]

you can see, my menu 'User Manual' has no any CSS applied, no background color. In my understanding, TIKI will make it ready for use out of box, however the menu in my environment make it hard to use, I have googled and tried many configurations in TIKI, however just can't figure it out.

pls help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because Tiki 13 changed to Bootstrap and Suckerfish CSS menus are no longer the default and there is no CSS for them anymore.

If you just want nice looking (Bootstrap styled) menu just go to Admin > Modules and assign the **Menu module** (instead of your custom menu module) with the following parameters:

- Menu: 43 (on the Module tab)
- Type: horiz
- No box: y (on the Appearance tab)

After you save the module you should see in the parameters:

```
id=43
type=horiz
nobox=y
```

If you want to use the Suckerfish menus (you still need to give them the CSS styling from Tiki 12):

- Menu: 43
- Type: horiz
- Use Bootstrap menus: n

Answer (score 0):

in the meantime some css was added for "old" standard non-bootstrap menus, as it appeared that many user still need to continue using non-Javascript css-menus.

In a late svn version of Tiki 13 I found some not so nice, but at least working css, but in Tiki pre-14 last svn-checkout from yesterday I have seen, that the css-menus by default appear cvonsistent to the bootstrap-menus now.

Hope the info helps.

And sorry for the inconveniences we are causing throughout the bootstrap transition process.

Regards,
Torsten